# Angular + Bootstrap css application across all pages

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap(http://www.getbootstrap.com) along with angularjs for development. My question is pretty straightforward : is there anyway I can make reference to the css once in my angularjs project and have that persist across all pages? or do I need to add this in the header of each view I create?

Comment: Typically this is done via templates; one main template where styles get imported and the app leverages those.

Comment: hm interesting. is there anywhere you could direct me on how to go about setting this up?

Comment: You'd want to look into scaffolding helpers like Yeoman.

Comment: ok. is there any way with yeoman to set this up after a project has been scaffolded?